# Writing native C++ code for Windows (Desktop) app in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, cross-platform, flutter-desktop

How can I write native code (C++ on Windows and Objective-C on macOS) in flutter for desktop app like [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab) in flutter docs for android and iOS platforms?
Can somebody show me a sample on GitHub repository or video on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop#writing-a-plugin has a variety of resources, including [a code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-github-client) and links to examples like [`url_launcher`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/url_launcher).